# Android Rounded Corners - XML vs Java version

Tags: android, xml, rounded-corners

We need rounded corner in some layouts and we came up with two approaches. Although both the approaches are working fine, the results are slightly different and I like to get some insights here on different behaviour.

The first approach is to use **XML**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#e1d6a6" />
    <corners android:radius="9dp" />
</shape>
```

This works. However, the problem with XML approach is that the color and the radius are fixed and we need to create duplicate drawables to just change any of the parameter. So we came up with the Java version which is much flexible and works like a charm, though with slightly different results. Below is the java version

```
void setRoundedCorners(View view, int color, float radius) {
    GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
    drawable.setColor(color);
    drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
    view.setBackground(drawable);
}
```

Although both the approaches are working fine, both requires different values in radius parameter to get the same effect. For example, if I use `android:radius="9dp"` in XML version, I need to use `setCornerRadius(30.0f)` in Java to get almost the same effect.

So I like to understand any cons in using Java approach and how 9dp in xml translates to setCornerRadius parameter in java for different devices. Any insight?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setCornerRadius` treat `float` value as pixels. You can provide same value `9dp` to this function by converting `dp` value to `px` according to device screen density and dimension

Following line gives you equivalent pixel value of `9dp`

```
TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Although, using `XML` gives great performance, behind the scene framework do this conversion to show same result on every device.